# Is there an easy test code for this ?

Tags: apex, unit-test

Is the only explanation for this that the test must have been deleted at some time, otherwise the class would not have been able to be put into production ? I've checked all of our sandboxes and there isn't one anywhere.

Does anybody know a quick test for this ?

```
public without sharing class CloneOpportunityWithDetails 
{   
    public PageReference cloneOpp()
    {
        Opportunity opp = [SELECT o.AccountId, o.OwnerId, o.Lead_Region__c, o.Retention_Status__c, o.Retention_Stoplight__c, o.Current_Contract_Start_Date__c, o.Current_Contract_Expiration_Date_del__c,o.Lead_Region_Detail__c, o.Lead_country__c, o.CloseDate, o.StageName
                        ,o.Sales_category__c, o.CurrencyIsoCode, o.Anticipated_Bid_Date__c, o.Id, o.Name, o.RecordTypeId,o.Sub_Stage__c
                        ,(SELECT cbc.Region__c, cbc.Region_Detail__c, cbc.Country__c, cbc.Air_Transactions__c, cbc.Air_Volume__c
                        ,cbc.Ferry_Transactions__c, cbc.Ferry_Volume__c, cbc.Hotel_Transactions__c, cbc.Hotel_Volume__c
                        ,cbc.Other_Transactions__c, cbc.Other_Volume__c, cbc.Rail_Transactions__c, cbc.Rail_Volume__c
                        ,cbc.Opportunity__c, cbc.Rental_Car_Transactions__c, cbc.Rental_Car_Volume__c, cbc.Name, cbc.Id, cbc.CurrencyIsoCode
                        ,cbc.Volumes_Transactions_are__c, cbc.Current_BCD_Travel_Rail_Volume__c, cbc.Current_BCD_Travel_Rail_Transactions__c
                        ,cbc.Current_BCD_Travel_Hotel_Volume__c, cbc.Current_BCD_Travel_Hotel_Transactions__c, cbc.Current_BCD_Travel_Ferry_Volume__c
                        ,cbc.Current_BCD_Travel_Ferry_Transactions__c, cbc.Current_BCD_Travel_Car_Volume__c
                        ,cbc.Current_BCD_Travel_Car_Transactions__c, cbc.Current_BCD_Travel_Air_Volume__c
                        ,cbc.Current_BCD_Travel_Air_Transactions__c
                         FROM County_by_Country__r cbc)
                        ,(SELECT bs.Account__c, bs.Business_Unit__c, bs.CurrencyIsoCode, bs.Current_Picture__c, bs.Future_Direction__c
                        ,bs.Opportunity_Plan__c, bs.Id, bs.IsDeleted, bs.Measures_Milestones__c, bs.Name, bs.Opportunity__c
                        ,bs.OwnerId, bs.Pains_Challenges__c 
                         FROM Business_Snapshot__r bs)
                        ,(SELECT otm.CreatedById, otm.CreatedBy.Id, otm.CreatedDate, otm.Id, otm.IsDeleted, otm.LastModifiedById
                        ,otm.LastModifiedDate, otm.OpportunityAccessLevel, otm.OpportunityId, otm.SystemModstamp, otm.TeamMemberRole
                        ,otm.UserId 
                         FROM OpportunityTeamMembers otm where otm.User.IsActive=true)
                        ,(SELECT  Id, ContactId, Role, IsPrimary, OpportunityId FROM OpportunityContactRoles)
                        FROM Opportunity o
                        WHERE o.Id = :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('oppId')];
        Opportunity oppClone = opp.clone(false,true);
        oppClone.Name = oppClone.Name + ' - Clone';
        oppClone.StageName='Qualifying';
        oppClone.Sub_Stage__c='Qualifying';
        Savepoint sp = Database.setSavepoint();
        try
        {
            insert oppClone;
            List<Country_by_Country__c> cbcList = new List<Country_by_Country__c>();
            List<Business_Snapshot__c> bsList = new List<Business_Snapshot__c>();
            List<OpportunityTeamMember> otmList = new List<OpportunityTeamMember>();
            List<OpportunityContactRole> ocrList = new List<OpportunityContactRole>();
            for(Country_by_Country__c cbc:oppClone.County_by_Country__r)
            {
                Country_by_Country__c cbcClone = cbc.clone(false,false);
                cbcClone.Opportunity__c=oppClone.Id;
                cbcList.add(cbcClone);
            }
            for(Business_Snapshot__c bs:oppClone.Business_Snapshot__r)
            {
                Business_Snapshot__c bsClone = bs.clone(false,false);
                bsClone.Opportunity__c = oppClone.Id;
                bsList.add(bsClone);
            }
            for(OpportunityTeamMember otm:oppClone.OpportunityTeamMembers)
            {
                OpportunityTeamMember otmClone = otm.clone(false,false);
                otmClone.OpportunityId = oppClone.Id;
                otmList.add(otmClone);
            }
            for(OpportunityContactRole ocr:oppClone.OpportunityContactRoles)
            {
                OpportunityContactRole ocrClone = ocr.clone(false,false);
                ocrClone.OpportunityId = oppClone.Id;
                ocrList.add(ocrClone);
            }
            if(cbcList.size()>0)
                insert cbcList;
            if(bsList.size()>0)
                insert bsList;
            if(otmList.size()>0)
                insert otmList;
            if(ocrList.size()>0)
                insert ocrList;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Database.rollback(sp);
            ApexPages.addMessages(e);
            return null;
        }
        return new PageReference('/'+oppClone.Id);
    }



}
```

The only change I've had to make was to just add some additional fields to be pulled right in the first line. If you can give me some help on a test code it would be great.

Thank you very much for your help & time.

Comment: Not necessarily; you only need 75% code coverage so a former developer could've skipped the test if enough other tests were in place.

Comment: But if it's in production then didn't there need to be a test written for it at some time in one of the sandboxes ?

Comment: No. It is completely possible to deploy code without a single line of it being covered, as long as it is not a trigger.  The only requirement is that triggers must have some code coverage and all of your code must have at least 75% coverage collectively.  For example, if you were already at, say, 90% and deployed this with no coverage your collective coverage might still be above 75%.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this article on [testing custom controllers](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_controller_error_handling.htm).

First thing in your test is to create records to test the clone with. You'll want to create an opportunity and all the records that are related to it (Country_by_Country__c, Business_Snapshot__c, OpportunityTeamMember, and OpportunityContactRole). It is ok to create these in a test class since they won't actually get saved.

Once you have the test records created, you need to add a parameter to your page, call the clone method and then check that a new opportunity was created.

Here's some code that won't work as is, but should get you started.

```
Opportunity testOp= new Opportunity(name = 'Test Op'); //you need to add all required fields here.
insert testOp;
//add the related records and insert them   
ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('id', testOp.Id);
cloneOpp = new CloneOpportunityWithDetails();
PageReference pr = cloneOpp.CloneOpp();

//finally test that the Opportunity was cloned by checking that you were redirected to an opportunity page.
```

Comment: Daniel - thanks so much for your input. It's probably gonna take me the rest of the day to complete that. Is there any way possible to get the class into production without writing a test code beforehand ? I can't find any test in the sandbox so I'm wondering how it got in production in the first place.

Comment: Your org's entire code coverage has to be at least 75%. It sounds like when this was developed, it had no tests and the developer was relying on the other test classes in the org to keep the code coverage above 75%. This is a very bad technique. The goal of writing test classes is not code cover per se, but really to ensure your code is doing what you think it is doing, not only now, but also during each change to the org.

Comment: Yha, I didn't intend to try and put the code into production w/out testing it myself. The reason I was asking if it is possible to do that is because I'm trying to figure out what might have happened to the test code since it was deployed. If it's not possible to get it into production w/out testing then I'm wondering if that means somebody deleted the code since the time it was deployed.

Comment: You can't remove anything from production without the tests running and ensuring code coverage is still good. Maybe the other tests rely on existing data and that data has been deleted? If that's the case, then your code coverage can plummet.